# Dynamic regex for date-time formats

Tags: regex, datetime, information-retrieval

Is there an existing solution to create a regular expressions dynamically out of a given date-time format pattern? The supported date-time format pattern does not matter (Joda `DateTimeFormat`, `java.text.SimpleDateTimeFormat` or others).

As a specific example, for a given date-time format like `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm`, it should generate the corresponding regular expression to match the date-times within the specified formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have a limited alphabet that your time formats can be constructed of. That means, `"HH"` would always be "hours" on the 24-hour clock, `"dd"` always the day with leading zero, and so on.

Because of the sequential nature of a time format, you could try to tokenize a format string of `"dd/mm/yyyy HH:nn"` into an array `["dd", "/", "mm", "/", "yyyy", " ", "HH", ":", "nn"]`. Then go ahead and form a pattern string from that array by replacing `"HH"` with `"([01][0-9]|2[0-3])"` and so on. Preconstruct these pattern atoms into a lookup table/array. All parts of your array that are not in the lookup table are literals. Escape them to according regex rules and append them to you pattern string.

---

EDIT: As a side effect for a regex based solution, when you put all regex "atoms" of your lookup table into parens and keep track of their order in a given format string, you would be able to use sub-matches to extract the required components from a match and feed them into a CreateDate function, thus skipping the ParseDate part altogether.

Comment: This works decently, but it is rather English-centric. "ddd" might be mapped to (mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun) then, but you'd need a locale-dependent mapping. It gets worse when the date format generates non-ASCII digits. See M.Kaplan's blog for far more details on i18n.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need. I thought to do something similar since I couldn't find anything that already exists. For parsing dateTimeFormat, I used jflex. So if it's "d" it should match 1 or 2 digits or if it's "ddd" it should match 3 digits etc. However, I still need to improve it for i18n.

Comment: @MSalters. Could you provide the link for the blog that you mentioned? Thanks

Comment: For locale-dependent patterns you could abstract that further and construct the lookup table from your language's locale date functions. Prior knowledge of the language your dates are are in is of course required, but then it is quite straight-forward.

Comment: Be aware that "dd" for "2 digits" will yield false positives. "99" would match, but certainly is not valid as a date component other than "two-digit year".

Comment: Yes it's obvious, I just didn't have enough chars  left to explain in more details while adding comment. The real burden is as MSalters said non-ASCII digits like japanese and arabic numbers. I think for each different type of digit sets, different regex should be created.

Comment: Of course. As I said, I think you can pull most of them out of locale specific date functions of your programming language of choice, and some of them might need to be hand-crafted, if you know what you do. I18N is hard if you take it to the max.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for basic date checking, this code matches this data.

```
\b(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)?[0-9]{2}\b

10/07/2008  
10.07.2008
1-01/2008
10/07/08    
10.07.2008
1-01/08
```

*Code via [regexbuddy](https://www.regexbuddy.com)*

Comment: what I need is a regex generator for the given DateTimeFormat. I don't know the date format used in the given corpus. So user first should provide by saying sth like DDMM hh:mm and I find these date values in the text. I've created sth by using JFlex. I will also post it here after I clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleDateFormat` already does this with the `parse()` method.

If you need to parse multiple dates from a single string, start with a regex (even if it matches too leniently), and use `parse()` on all the potential matches found by the regex.

Comment: it only parses if the given text matches the pattern and returns the Date object representation of that string. It doesn't parse if the date information is somewhere within the other texts. 
like "sometext 12/03/2004 sometext.

Comment: That might be undecidable.  What if the text contains two dates, e.g. "Between A and B, blah" where A and B are dates...

Comment: well, then will find them as two groups, just like a regex find.

Answer (score 0):

The below given js / jQuery code is for dynamically generated RegEx for the Date format only, not for DateTime (Development version not fully tested yet.)

Date Format should be in "*D M Y*".

E.g.

> - DD-MM-YY
> - DD-MM-YYYY
> - YYYY-MM-DD
> - YYYY-DD-MM
> - MM-DD-YYYY
> - MM-DD-YY
> - DD/MM/YY
> - DD/MM/YYYY
> - YYYY/MM/DD
> - YYYY/DD/MM
> - MM/DD/YYYY
> - MM/DD/YY

Or other formats but created with  "*D M Y*" characters:

```
var dateFormat = "DD-MM-YYYY";
var order = [];
    var position = {"D":dateFormat.search('D'),"M":dateFormat.search('M'),"Y":dateFormat.search('Y')};
    var count = {"D":dateFormat.split("D").length - 1,"M":dateFormat.split("M").length - 1,"Y":dateFormat.split("Y").length - 1};
    var seprator ='';
    for(var i=0; i<dateFormat.length; i++){
  if(["Y","M","D"].indexOf(dateFormat.charAt(i))<0){
    seprator = dateFormat.charAt(i);
  }else{
    if(order.indexOf(dateFormat.charAt(i)) <0 ){
        order.push(dateFormat.charAt(i));
    }
  }
    }
    var regEx  = "^";
    $(order).each(function(ok,ov){
    regEx  += '(\d{'+count[ov]+'})'+seprator;
    });
    regEx = regEx.substr(0,(regEx.length)-1);
  regEx  +="$";
  var re = new RegExp(regEx);
  console.log(re);
```

NOTE: There is no validation check for months / days
e.g. month should be in 01-12 or date should be in 01-31